# How do I override configuration in application.yml in spring boot (2.4.2) generated docker image?

Tags: spring-boot

1. I used spring boot 2.4.2
2. Generated docker image using the command **mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=XXXXXX.azurecr.io/fake-XXXXX:0215**
3. I have hostnames in application.yml that I need to override
4. So I passed -Dspring.data.mongodb.host=mongo_db in docker-compose under **command: BUT it is not overriding.** .. Below screenshot for reference.
   [image]
5. I understand that Buildpacks are used to build the layered jar.
6. If this was docker image created by me manually and not by spring boot then I would have ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile and command in docker-compose where I would have given command: Dspring.data.mongodb.host=mongo_db -jar fake-XXXX.jar
7. I know #6 works but would like to use the latest and greatest spring boot in my new project. Hence kindly let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the approach via Spring Config or Harshi Corp Consul KV feature and read your config from there. Check-in your config to a repo and have config framework read it from there and pass it to your app?  You can change the config at runtime (probably requires restart of containers to reload the modified KV fields in some case)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes there are other ways to get around this for eg like you said I can have a config server or I can extract them in to K8s config or I can go back to #6 but I would like to understand how ENTRYPOINT, COMMAND, executable jar file i.e layered jar file are glued together. I love this feature of using spring boot to create docker image rather creating it manually.  spring boot folks in github instructed to raise questions here. I would be happy if they would take questions in their github itself. Will read thru their doc again to try my luck